# Where do "Deciding which technology to use" questions belong on the network?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, technology

I often face people asking questions, about which technology is best to use in a particular software development task. Whether [Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) is better than [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) when it comes to server-to-server communication, etc. If the question is asked at Stack Overflow it is most likely to get closed, because it is general and is not discussing a particular software development problem.

Is there a Stack Exchange community, where such questions can be discussed among software developers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with these questions is that unless you are very specific about your requirements all you get is either a list of people's favourite technology or an argument in comments about which technology is "better".

In general these questions are off topic for Programmers too - we explicitly mention this in our [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq).

The truth is that these days, unless you have a really specific problem, there can be little to choose from between technologies. This means that your question is either "not constructive" or "too localised".

What's more important is **your** familiarity with the technology and problem space. If you are a Ruby on Rails developer then it probably makes sense to use that for your server-to-server application.

For more information on this area see [Gorilla vs Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark)

Comment: Yeah. Most of these questions are so unspecific, they remind me of Ali G asking a Gender researcher: "Which one is better - man or woman?" http://youtu.be/sBtDOD-QKSw?t=36s

Comment: Thank you. As an ASP.NET developer that knows very little about Ruby and PHP, I am amazed at how short their code snippets usually are, whereas the same functionality in .net would take much more coding effort. That is why I think that questions like "which technology is better" are specific enough in their own sense. When someone asks which design pattern is best at a particular situation, the responses are also usually a set of personal opinions, but these questions pass the "off-topic"'ness test.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov - the design pattern questions *should* be judged by the same rule, but they are different as they are an implementation question.

Comment: @Scrooge - when there is a particular task described in a question, and it is being asked, which technology is best (easiest) for solving it, it is the same implementation question, right?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov - That was my point about "being specific".

Comment: @Scrooge - so, in case I am stating a problem and asking which technology is best at solving it, I am asking a correct question that is not to be closed?

Comment: @Maxim Yes, but if your problem is "I want to make a website" or something similarly broad and generic, it might not be enough.